# How to add description comments on schema.graphql on AWS Amplify CLI At time of amplify Push

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I need to add  description of types  comments on my local project with amplify, after at time of push i need upload the comments on the schema too, for generate the JSON of Introspection schema with the comments, I already make this with AWS AppSync manually, but I need make that on **amplify push**...

For example:

```
.........   
# [Type comment here]

type Todo @model {

  id: ID!

  name: String!

  description: String

}

.......
```

When I generate the **introspection schema** json:

```
......
    {
                        "kind": "OBJECT",
                        "name": "Todo",
                        "description": " Todo - Mycomment",
                        "fields": [
                            {
                                "name": "nome",
                                "description": null,
                                "args": [],
                                "type": {
                                    "kind": "NON_NULL",
                                    "name": null,
                                    "ofType": {
                                        "kind": "SCALAR",
                                        "name": "String",
                                        "ofType": null
                                    }



.......
```

I need make this at time of amplify push and not change manually on AppSync.